# d3.nest return sum of values for each row

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a csv like that:

```
name,na,profile,one,two,three,four,
uni1,eng,impact,4,5,3,1
uni1,eng,overall,10,5,3,1
uni1,fr,impact,4,5,7,1
uni1,fr,overall,20,5,7,1
uni1,ger,impact,4,5,3,1
uni1,ger,overall,18,5,18,1
uni1,eng,impact,4,5,3,1
uni2,eng,overall,4,5,3,1
uni2,fr,impact,4,5,3,30
uni2,fr,overall,4,5,3,1
uni2,ger,impact,4,5,3,1
uni2,ger,overall,4,21,3,1
uni2,spain,impact,4,5,3,1
uni2,spain,overall,4,5,3,1
uni2,spain,impact,4,20,3,1
uni2,lat,overall,4,19,3,1
uni2,lat,impact,4,5,17,1
```

I would like to compute a d3 nest that will returned me for each uni and na the sum of the the one two three four value when `profile === overall`.

I woul like to have an array of object like :

```
array[object0{uni1{
                  eng{
                  value:230}]
```

I succed to get all the line with the overall value but  I do not know how to return such things...

```
var nestedData = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d){return (d.profile=== "Overall").forEach(d.name);})
            //.rollup(function (v) { return d3.sum(v,function(d){return (d.four*4,d.three*3,d.two*2,d.one)/100 });})
            .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
            .entries(filteredData());

        console.log("Ranked :data",nestedData);

        return nestedData;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your desired outcome is not exactly clear because you didn't show us how do you want to position the inner array for different `eng` in the same `uni`.

Therefore, here is an solution (out of many), check the console to see the array's structure:

```js
var csv = `name,na,profile,one,two,three,four,
uni1,eng,impact,4,5,3,1
uni1,eng,overall,10,5,3,1
uni1,fr,impact,4,5,7,1
uni1,fr,overall,20,5,7,1
uni1,ger,impact,4,5,3,1
uni1,ger,overall,18,5,18,1
uni1,eng,impact,4,5,3,1
uni2,eng,overall,4,5,3,1
uni2,fr,impact,4,5,3,30
uni2,fr,overall,4,5,3,1
uni2,ger,impact,4,5,3,1
uni2,ger,overall,4,21,3,1
uni2,spain,impact,4,5,3,1
uni2,spain,overall,4,5,3,1
uni2,spain,impact,4,20,3,1
uni2,lat,overall,4,19,3,1
uni2,lat,impact,4,5,17,1`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  d.one = +d.one;
  d.two = +d.two;
  d.three = +d.three;
  d.four = +d.four;
  return d;
});

var filteredData = data.filter(function(d) {
  return d.profile === "overall"
});

var nestedData = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.na
  })
  .rollup(function(v) {
    return v[0].one + v[0].two + v[0].three + v[0].four
  })
  .entries(filteredData);

console.log(nestedData)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

PS: I know it's just me, but I was never a great fan of `d3.nest()`. I prefer to manipulate the data array the way I want with plain JavaScript functions... it's more versatile and you can structure the outcome exactly as you need.

**EDIT**: answering the [*Friday-challenge*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341065/d3-nest-return-sum-of-values-for-each-row#comment81648130_47341334), this is the vanilla JavaScript to create the outcome described by OP (almost, because the inner objects have to be inside an array):

```
var finalArray = [];

[...new Set(filteredData.map(function(d) {
    return d.name
}))].forEach(function(d) {
    var tempObj = {
        [d]: []
    };
    filteredData.filter(function(e) {
        return e.name === d;
    }).forEach(function(e) {
        tempObj[d].push({
            [e.na]: e.one + e.two + e.three + e.four
        })
    });
    finalArray.push(tempObj)
});
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var csv = `name,na,profile,one,two,three,four,
uni1,eng,impact,4,5,3,1
uni1,eng,overall,10,5,3,1
uni1,fr,impact,4,5,7,1
uni1,fr,overall,20,5,7,1
uni1,ger,impact,4,5,3,1
uni1,ger,overall,18,5,18,1
uni1,eng,impact,4,5,3,1
uni2,eng,overall,4,5,3,1
uni2,fr,impact,4,5,3,30
uni2,fr,overall,4,5,3,1
uni2,ger,impact,4,5,3,1
uni2,ger,overall,4,21,3,1
uni2,spain,impact,4,5,3,1
uni2,spain,overall,4,5,3,1
uni2,spain,impact,4,20,3,1
uni2,lat,overall,4,19,3,1
uni2,lat,impact,4,5,17,1`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  d.one = +d.one;
  d.two = +d.two;
  d.three = +d.three;
  d.four = +d.four;
  return d;
});

var filteredData = data.filter(function(d) {
  return d.profile === "overall"
});

var finalArray = [];

[...new Set(filteredData.map(function(d) {
  return d.name
}))].forEach(function(d) {
  var tempObj = {
    [d]: []
  };
  filteredData.filter(function(e) {
    return e.name === d;
  }).forEach(function(e) {
    tempObj[d].push({
      [e.na]: e.one + e.two + e.three + e.four
    })
  });
  finalArray.push(tempObj)
});

console.log(finalArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"I prefer to manipulate the data array the way I want"* —that's because **you** can ;-) It's always a tradeoff between ease of use, versatility, flexibility, performance, right? And, arguably, it's a close call for `d3.nest()`. Since you brought up the issue, though, I *Friday-challenge* you to add a snippet doing this in vanilla JS!